# How can I search through an Excel array to find specific text and then generate a new array that contains the values from those cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large list of organic compounds, some of which are chlorinated and some are not.  I have tried to write a function that looks through the list of organic compounds and generates a new array of only those compounds which are chlorinated.  Here is the result I have so far:

You can see that the function is correctly pulling all chlorinated compounds, but ideally I'd like to have a list that ignores all compounds which do not meet the criteria instead of returning a "no" value.  What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: If you want to ignore the `no` and return those are `Chlorinated` only then you need to use the `FILTER()` function, all you have to do is scrap the `IF()` part and keep the rest within `FILTER()` that said, the formula will be `=FILTER(A3:A83,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("chl",A3:A83)),"")`

Comment: Ahhh yes, thank you this is what I was looking for.  If you post this as an answer I'll be sure to mark it as the official answer.

Comment: Sounds Great, let me do that. Posted Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked by OP, posting it as answer.

[image]

---

Using **[FILTER()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)** Function does the job, only have to scrap the `IF()` part.

That said the formula will be:

```
=FILTER(A3:A83,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("chl",A3:A83)),"")
```